# vertx sync config retrieval behaves unexpectedly

Tags: kotlin, vert.x

In my multi-verticle application, I would like to load the config once and then inject the resulting `JsonObject` into each verticle using koin. The problem is that the `ConfigRetriever` doesn't really behave the way I would expect it to. Consider the following example:

```
class MainVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {
  override fun start() {
    val retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx)
    val config = ConfigRetriever.getConfigAsFuture(retriever).result()
    println(config)
  }
}
```

Intuitively I would expect this to load the config file under `/resources/conf/config.json` and print all the key/value pairs. Instead of doing that, it prints `null`. However, if I change the third line to:

```
val retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(Vertx.vertx())
```

then the `JsonObject` gets populated with the properties of my `config.json` file.

The docs of `Future#result` state the following

> The result of the operation. This will be null if the operation failed.

So the operation succeeds but no config is loaded?

**I don't really understand why I have to create a new `vertx` instance for the config to be loaded properly. What am I missing here?**

Comment: When you call `Vertx.vertx()` you create a new Vert.x instance. Not sure exactly why config retriever works when you do that, need more info. If you want to understand the failure you need to get the `cause()` instead of `result()`.

Comment: Both `result()` and `cause()` return null. I'm guessing that the future is never completed.

Comment: You must inspect the future in a handler: `future.setHandler({ar -> ...})`

Comment: I need to get the result of the future in a blocking fashion, so that I can use it for dependency injection with koin / guice. Think of it like the result of a `@Provides` method. The async handler isn't really an option here but maybe there are other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: there is a method which returns a cached version of the config https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-config/java/#_retrieving_the_last_retrieved_configuration

So all I had to do is to load the config once in `@Provides` method:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public ConfigRetriever config(Vertx vertx) {
    final ConfigRetriever retriever = ConfigRetriever.create(vertx);

    // Retrieving the config here is not just to print it,
    // but also to create a cached config which can be later used in Configuration
    try {
        final var cfg = retriever.getConfig().toCompletionStage().toCompletableFuture().get();
        cfg.stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().startsWith("backend") && !entry.getKey().contains("pass"))
            .forEach(entry -> log.info("{} = {}", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));

        return retriever;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```